# 404 error when loading a image

Tags: image, extjs, http-status-code-404

I used ext js framework to build my web site. but there is alway a image that cannot be found, that means always return a 404 error. the image link is "http://localhost/undefined". I checked the HTML, and did not found any  tag that its link is like this.
I wonder if I miss some steps when using the ext js framework, do any one know this issues?

Comment: Some code would be nice?

Answer (score 1):

have you try define the Ext blank image ??

try this :

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
   Ext.BLANK_IMAGE_URL = '../extjs/resources/images/default/s.gif';
   .....
   //your code
   .......
});
```

if still not solve.. try update your question with your current code..